# Translate Flutter App with data provided by backend

Tags: flutter, dart, translation, backend

What is the best practice to manage the translation of an entire app developed in Flutter with data coming from the backend?

This is an example of the data sent to me from the backend, after providing language code (ex: es, it, en)

```
{
    "locale": {
        "es": {
           . . .
           "disclaimer": "Renuncia",
           "date": {
             . . .
              "day_names": [
                    "domingo",
                    "lunes",
                    "martes",
                    "miércoles",
                    "jueves",
                    "viernes",
                    "sábado"
              ],
              . . .
          }
          . . .
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `AppLocalizationDelegate` for that.
It has a load function which you can use to load the desired json into the memory.

At first the app should contain a fallback language file in case it fails to load the translations from the server.

But after you load the translations and decode them (inside app localizations delegate)  you should change the locale.

Changing the locale will force the app localizations delegate to call its reload method which will take the newly loaded translations.

**Update**

Take a look
[In the official docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization%20in%20the%20official%20docs)
for an example with local translation files